# Jquery how to hide form on submit and show a link to show the form again

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am new to jQuery and here is the thing that i want to ask. Below is the HTML code,

```
<div>
  <!-- Div One -->
  <div class="search_tag">
    <span>Show search From</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Div Two -->
  <div class="search">
    <form>
      ......
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, When the page loads, i want the Div Two i.e `<div class="search">` to be shown and the Div one i.e `<div class="search_tag>` to hide. When i click on form submit, the page will refresh and i want the form to hide i.e `<div class="search">` and the `<div class="search_tag">` to show up. When i click on the Div one i.e `<div class="search_tag">` i want the Div two i.e `<div class="search">` form to show up and i would make another form submission. I need to do this with jQuery.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** : *i don't need the form button event, i need the form submit event where the page will refresh.*

Comment: If you want the page to refresh you will loose any jQuery settings on the div tags.  I would suggest looking into Ajax form submission.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the form submission using javascript or jQuery to do something like this ?

Comment: Yes, you can see [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="toggleSearch"></span>
<input id="submit" class="submit" type="button" value="submit" />

$('#toggleSearch').onclick(function() {
  $('.search').toggle();
  $('.search_tag').toggle();
});


$('#submit').onclick(function() {
  $('.search').toggle();
  $('.search_tag').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Is it `click` or `onclick`?

Comment: Why would i need the span with a toggleSearch id and a onclick event on it. ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is close to what you would want, I think it will help. (The thing you want exactly follows from it pretty easily.)

```
<div id="search_tag">
    Show search form
</div>

<div id="search">
    <form id="myform">
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="button" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->

var form_submitted = false;
refresh();

$('#myform').click(function() {
    form_submitted = true;
    refresh();
});

$('#search_tag').click(function() {
    form_submitted = false;
    refresh();
});

function refresh() {
    $('#search').toggle(!form_submitted);
    $('#search_tag').toggle(form_submitted);
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FZfxN/

Comment: Should i use only id's for this, or can i use classes too ?

Comment: should i put all of this Jquery code inside the $(document).ready(function() {.your code..}); ? How does it work ?

Comment: you have given the code for the button click event, but i need the code for the form submit event. That's where the problem is, the page refreshes.

Comment: **(A)** The page doesn't have to refresh, it's your choice. Using JavaScript (in this case jQuery) you can do it without the page refreshing. **(B)** Yes, you should wrap that code inside `$(document).ready(function() {...})`. Jsfiddle does this in the background, which is why I didn't have to. **(C)** You generally use IDs when you have only one of something, and classes when you have many. It doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.search form input[value="submit"]').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.search').hide();
    })

    $('.search_tag').click(function(){
        $('.search').toggle()
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZbS3x/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.search_tag').hide();
$('.search_tag').click(function(){ $(this).toggle(); $('.search').toggle();});
$('.search').click(function(){ $(this).toggle(); $('.search_tag').toggle(); });
});
```

Here is my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/TPH7u/)

You could also do a little AJAX to send the the form data every time submit button is clicked without having to refresh by adding the code below:

```
 $('#demoform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent from following the link
    $.post('mytest.php'); // and just post here if you are using php
});
```

Ajax Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdy_dot/TPH7u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 // please set ID attribute for all control

**HTML**
<div>
   <!-- Div One -->
   <div class="search_tag" id="search">
   <span id="show">Show search From</span>
   </div>

   <!-- Div Two -->
   <div class="search" id="submitButton">
     <form>
     ......
     <input class="submit" type="button" value="submit" id="submit" />
   </form>
  </div>
</div>


function pageLoad()
{
  $('#search').hide();


  $('#submit').click(function(){

    $('#submitButton').hide();
    $('#search').show();

  })

  $('#show').click(function(){

    $('#submitButton').show();        

  })



}
```

Please try it and then let me know if you face any problems...

Comment: The input type in the form must be a submit. Then the page will refresh.